# Smarty templates don't refresh on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, smarty, lamp

At work a use Smarty templates (on WAMP) in a Windows environment. All just works fine. Just when I want this to make it work at home with LAMP on Ubuntu something strange happens: I see my Smarty templates work in the browser just as normal, but when I make a change in my .tpl file Apache does not seem to catch up with the new template state. I don't get an error or something, I just keep on seeing the same old template, like it's cached forever. Apache restart does not fix this. Has anybody a clou on this?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't $compile_check parameter set to "false" at home? 
It's "true" by default, but maybe you've set it to "false" somewhere?
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/variable.compile.check.tpl

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Smarty caching then that is most certainly the problem.

Try to flush cache. Before command `$smarty->display('template.tpl')` try to put:

```
// clear only cache for template.tpl
$smarty->clear_cache('template.tpl');
```

or

```
// clear out all cache files
$smarty->clear_all_cache();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you try delete contents of template_c/ and cache/ folders.Than try again to load page.

Comment: Ah, I was just looking at cached files. When I cleared the template_c directory my site stopped working at all. I just get an empty page. Now my issue looks more like this unresolved one: [smarty works in xampp environment but not in ubuntu apache environment. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692412/smarty-works-in-xampp-environment-but-not-in-ubuntu-apache-environment-why). However, I don't get any error while error reporting seems to be enabled:
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: OK, found it. After clearing my templates_c directory it appeared that this folder had no writing permissions. I gave it a chmod 777 and now it works fine. Thanks for putting me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

After clearing my templates_c directory it appeared that this folder had no writing permissions. I gave it a chmod 777 and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by adding these two lines after "$smarty = new Smarty;"

```
$smarty->caching = false;
$smarty->force_compile = true;
```

This is handy for development, but should be avoided in production.